# How to integrate Google calender in an android app?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am building an android app where I need to integrated Google calender in my application so that the user gets a notification and save their note.

I have searched in google without any result.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks! can you please give me other example or other easy way please

Comment: http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Answer (score 1):

The Calendar Provider is a repository for a user's calendar events. The Calendar Provider API allows you to perform query, insert, update, and delete operations on calendars, events, attendees, reminders, and so on.

more details ::-

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html